# How can I unpack binary hex formatted data in Python?

Tags: python, binary, hex

Using the PHP [pack()](http://www.php.net/pack) function, I have converted a string into a binary hex representation:

```
$string = md5(time); // 32 character length
$packed = pack('H*', $string);
```

The H* formatting means "Hex string, high nibble first".

To unpack this in PHP, I would simply use the [unpack()](http://www.php.net/unpack) function with the H* format flag.

How would I unpack this data in Python?

Comment: you have your terminology horribly confused.

Comment: @hop: Other than "binary hex", its all OK.  There's just a little cross-language vocabulary difference.  It confused me at first till I read the definition of PHP's pack(), but its just a matter of different terms being used.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's an easy way to do this with the `binascii` module:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> print binascii.hexlify("ABCZ")
'4142435a'
>>> print binascii.unhexlify("4142435a")
'ABCZ'
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding something about the nibble ordering (high-nibble first is the default… anything different is insane), that should be perfectly sufficient!

Furthermore, Python's `hashlib.md5` objects have a `hexdigest()` method to automatically convert the MD5 digest to an ASCII hex string, so that this method isn't even necessary for MD5 digests.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 11):

There's no corresponding "hex nibble" code for struct.pack, so you'll either need to manually pack into bytes first, like:

```
hex_string = 'abcdef12'

hexdigits = [int(x, 16) for x in hex_string]
data = ''.join(struct.pack('B', (high <<4) + low) 
               for high, low in zip(hexdigits[::2], hexdigits[1::2]))
```

Or better, you can just use the hex codec.  ie.

```
>>> data = hex_string.decode('hex')
>>> data
'\xab\xcd\xef\x12'
```

To unpack, you can encode the result back to hex similarly

```
>>> data.encode('hex')
'abcdef12'
```

However, note that for your example, there's probably no need to take the round-trip through a hex representation at all when encoding.  Just use the md5 binary digest directly.  ie.

```
>>> x = md5.md5('some string')
>>> x.digest()
'Z\xc7I\xfb\xee\xc96\x07\xfc(\xd6f\xbe\x85\xe7:'
```

This is equivalent to your pack()ed representation.  To get the hex representation, use the same unpack method above:

```
>>> x.digest().decode('hex')
'acbd18db4cc2f85cedef654fccc4a4d8'
>>> x.hexdigest()
'acbd18db4cc2f85cedef654fccc4a4d8'
```

[Edit]: Updated to use better method (hex codec)

Comment: In the first version, is there anything special to import to use the group statement?

Comment: @Leandro:  Oops - group() was a function in my own library (break a sequence into groups of N characters).  I've updated the code to just use a slice to avoid the undefined function.

Answer (score 8):

In Python you use the [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module for this.

```
>>> from struct import *
>>> pack('hhl', 1, 2, 3)
'\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03'
>>> unpack('hhl', '\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03')
(1, 2, 3)
>>> calcsize('hhl')
8
```

HTH

Comment: Note : "h" means something different in struct than "nibble encoded as hex" - it refers to a 16 bit integer.