# from php to django for pack('H32',$challenge) and md5("\0" . $word . $challenge)

Tags: php, python, django, md5, pack

i have the following functions called one after the other in PHP :

```
$chal = pack('H32',$challenge);
$word = md5("\0" . $word . $chal);
```

I would like to do the same in Django python. 
Any tips from your side please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach produces the same result as the original php (at least on x86_64).

```
import hashlib
import struct

cha1 = struct.pack('16B', *[int(c, 16) for c in (challenge[i:i+2]
    for i in xrange(0, len(challenge), 2))])

word = hashlib.md5('\0%s%s' % (word, cha1)).hexdigest()
```

Python's struct.pack() method doesn't have a format specifier for a 4-bit size (single hex char), which seems to be roughly what php's pack() is doing.  So you have to break the original challenge string up into to 2-char chunks and interpret each of those as a hex octet.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! i was wondering why pack would give me wrong results, now i understand better

Answer (score 0):

This might be of some help [how-can-i-unpack-binary-hex-formatted-data-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200738/how-can-i-unpack-binary-hex-formatted-data-in-python)